# Jquery Load Gets Data, Not Inserting into Element

Tags: php, jquery

I'm loading some external data into a div via load(). The load() "works", in that I can inspect the page in Chrome and see under the Network log that the loaded page was called, and the appropriate response was received. The load function itself will produce a callback response if I add one. However, no html is added to my element. I have tried:

- loading a different url **(edit: this works, so it must just be my file**?)
- inserting the loaded html into a different element
- moving the function inside and outside the document ready
- using "get" instead of load
- removing all other scripts except jquery and my custom js file
- Executing the function via the console works when I copy/paste my load function, but only on the second try (??!?!).

Function that controls when the load function is executed

```
$(document).on("click",".keyword", function () {

    var keywordRef = $(this).text();
    showKeywordStats(keywordRef);

});
```

Function performing the load

```
function showKeywordStats (keyword)
{
    $("#keywordStats").load("getKeywordStats.php?keyword=" + keyword);
}
```

The div receiving the loaded url

```
<div id="keywordStats"></div>
```

The content of the url being loaded (for testing purposes):

```
<?php
echo "I should appear";
?>
```

When I add a line to the showKeywordStats() function:

```
function showKeywordStats (keyword)
{
     //added line below
     $("#keywordStats").html('Did i disappear?');
     $("#keywordStats").load("getKeywordStats.php?keyword=" + keyword);
}
```

"Did i disappear?" shows up for a second, and then the div is emptied, without the contents of the loaded url.

I am totally mystified. I have two other load functions on the page that work fine, but this one does not. Any ideas?

Comment: Although I agree it shouldn't matter did you make sure that what you are loading contains at least some html like maybe wrap "i should appear" in a div and then try? Also is it possible that you need to wrap your .load line in a setTimeout(function(){},0); ?

Comment: Just tried wrapping the php output in <div> tags, no result. Same with the set timeout, and tried different lengths as well (0, 5000). Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It had to do with the  url parameters that I was passing in my load() url. The parameter was somehow getting passed with trailing spaces, which didn't bother the actual GET portion of the load() function, but jQuery wouldn't show the loaded html until I trimmed out the spaces from the url.